# cabal install cabal-install errors out on linux

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

Am using linux (centos 6.6).When I try to run cabal install cabal-install command am getting following errors

```
cabal: cannot configure unix-2.7.0.1. It requires base >=4.5 && <4.8
For the dependency on base >=4.5 && <4.8 there are these packages:
base-4.5.0.0, base-4.5.1.0, base-4.6.0.0, base-4.6.0.1, base-4.7.0.0 and
base-4.7.0.1. However none of them are available.
base-4.5.0.0 was excluded because base-4.3.1.0 was selected instead
base-4.5.0.0 was excluded because of the top level dependency base -any
base-4.5.1.0 was excluded because base-4.3.1.0 was selected instead
base-4.5.1.0 was excluded because of the top level dependency base -any
base-4.6.0.0 was excluded because base-4.3.1.0 was selected instead
base-4.6.0.0 was excluded because of the top level dependency base -any
base-4.6.0.1 was excluded because base-4.3.1.0 was selected instead
base-4.6.0.1 was excluded because of the top level dependency base -any
base-4.7.0.0 was excluded because base-4.3.1.0 was selected instead
base-4.7.0.0 was excluded because of the top level dependency base -any
base-4.7.0.1 was excluded because base-4.3.1.0 was selected instead
base-4.7.0.1 was excluded because of the top level dependency base -any
```

Note: caball-install version 0.10.2
using version 1.10.2.0 of the Cabal library
GHC version  7.0.4
haskell-platform-2011.4.0.0-6.el6.x86_64

How to resolve it.pls help!

Comment: Those versions are ancient. You probably want to reinstall cabal/ghc from scratch.

Comment: Can you give me a link to download latest version. If I try to download those,using yum install command am getting only older version. Should I update the repositories or what should I do to resolve these dependencies issue?

Comment: I'd recommend looking at: https://github.com/bitemyapp/learnhaskell#getting-started https://github.com/fpco/stackage/wiki/Preparing-your-system-to-use-Stackage#other-linux

Comment: @Michael-When trying to update cabal from the link which you provided am getting following errors:`No instance for (NFData Version)
      arising from a use of `rnf'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (NFData Version)
    In the second argument of `seq', namely `rnf version'
    In the expression: rnf name `seq` rnf version
    In an equation for `rnf':
        rnf (PackageIdentifier name version) = rnf name `seq` rnf version

Error during cabal-install bootstrap:
Compiling the Setup script failed.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is because of an old version of ghc-7.0.4.I downloaded ghc 7.8.3 source tarball from [here](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_8_3) and installed it.

Then ghc 7.8.3 had old version of cabal so, have to unregister it from ghc 7.8.3 using 
`ghc unregister Cabal` .

Then run bootstrap.sh from cabal-install-1.20 folder and got cabal-install 1.20 successfully.